# Invoice design, not printing to edge of page

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing

We have sales invoice which we need to print on an ongoing basis, I have attached a screen capture of the invoice in Microsoft Word.

[image]

Where the orange part is, its not printing to the edge, we've tried to edit the margins etc and nothing works.

It looks like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make word to print the header picture from the edge of the page](http://superuser.com/questions/433764/how-to-make-word-to-print-the-header-picture-from-the-edge-of-the-page)

Answer (score 2):

Photo-capable printers can often be set to print right to the edge of the paper for borderless prints.  Most non-photo printers can't.  Many general-purpose printers that also do borderless photos will be limited to doing edge-to-edge printing only in photo-mode.

If that is really important to you, there are a few options.  You could have the paper stock pre-printed with the orange band (and any other content that doesn't change), print the band as you do now and trim the paper afterwards, or look for paper stock with tear-off edges.  Getting the paper stock pre-printed is probably the most cost effective option.  If you do it in any significant quantity, the cost per sheet is not much more than the paper, itself, plus you save your own expensive ink or toner.